# Create one code client / flatten controllers with NSwag and AutoREST

Tags: swagger, nswag, autorest

I'm trying to create a code wrapper for an api with NSwag and Autorest.

Previously I was using Swashbuckle to generate the swagger file. It generated the swagger file with operationIds in the format `actionMethod`. This resulted in Autorest generating a code client that was 1-deep. All of the actions were on the top-level class.

For various reasons, I needed to change swagger generation to NSwag. This generates operationIds in the format `controller_actionMethod`. This results in AutoRest creating a composite class that exposes separate classes with actions for each controller.

How can either

- Change how NSwag generates the operationIds
- Change how Autorest maps operationIds

Note: I know I can manually change the swagger.json, but I'd like to keep a consistent automated process for generating the code client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any readily available settings, but you can hook into the generation process of NSwag

https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/Document-Processors-and-Operation-Processors#operation-processors

The operation processor

```cs
class FlattenOperationsProcessor: IOperationProcessor
{
    public async Task<bool> ProcessAsync(OperationProcessorContext context)
    {
        context.OperationDescription.Operation.OperationId = $"{context.MethodInfo.Name}";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then add it in Startup.cs

```cs
document.OperationProcessors.Add(new FlattenOperationsProcessor());
```

Comment: exacly :
services.AddOpenApiDocument(document => 
    document.OperationProcessors.Add(new FlattenOperationsProcessor()))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was available when the question was asked, but here is a pretty easy way to do it:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.CustomOperationIds(d => d.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor ? controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.Name : d.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo?.Name);
});
```

The same can also be set via `c.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.OperationIdSelector`

Note that `ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo?.Name` is the default I used from the source code [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/60b018c7b83e6acc57b44ee905155524d0fbca3a/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SwaggerGenerator/SwaggerGeneratorOptions.cs#L64)